# Adding to functions.php in child theme doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm just trying to translate some text on my blog and it happens to be in functions.php. I'm using a child theme with its own functions.php where I've already added some modified code from the original functions.php without any issues. Now for example I have this code in the original functions.php:

```
/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Custom Search Form
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

function infinity_search_form( $value = false ) {
    $placeholder = esc_html__( 'Search...', 'flexblog');
    if ( $value === true ) {
        $placeholder = esc_html__('Type and hit Enter...', 'flexblog');
    }

    $form  = '<form method="get" action="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'" class="infinity-search" >';
        $form .= '<input id="s" class="search_input" type="text" name="s" placeholder="'. $placeholder .'">';
        $form .= '<button type="submit" class="submit button" name="submit" ><i class="fa fa-search" ></i></button>';
    $form .= '</form>';

    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'infinity_search_form' );
```

And all I want to change is "Type and hit Enter...". I translate the text, then I copy and paste everything in the child theme's functions.php just like I did here (but with the translated text). The text doesn't show up as translated on the blog (shows up the same) and the back-end (WP dashboard) just breaks completely (it says there's some error in functions.php - the original one, even though it's untouched - on line XXX, where the original code that I modified in the child theme's functions.php is located).

If I simply replace the text in the original functions.php, it works fine. But I want to use the functions.php from the child theme, for obvious reasons.

Like I mentioned, I already have some code added in the child theme's functions.php and I did it the same way and it worked - copy the whole function and add it to child theme, edit what I need to edit, and that's it. But this time it isn't working.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You cant override functions, they have to be uniquely named.  You get something like, `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare infinity_search_form IN ...`, no? Best bet is to rename your "Fixed" copy, search through the theme and override any file (or actions) that uses the old one, to use the new.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Parent theme functions can be overridden in a child theme, the process simply changes from implementation to implementation: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623

Comment: There I added `(or Actions)` ... Good link though.  But it's up to how well the parent them has been setup to be used by a child theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the function is written in the parent theme, you can certainly override the parent function. In the parent functions.php file, is it a pluggable function (does it look like this)?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'infinity_search_form' ) ) {
    function infinity_search_form( $value = false ) {
```

If it appears like that, then simply declaring a new copy of the function in your child theme functions.php file.

If it doesn't appear like that, then the function is not pluggable, and you will have to initialize it in another way. The best bet would be to declare it after the parent declaration (see the example below):

```
function infinity_search_form( $value = false ) {
    $placeholder = esc_html__( 'Search...', 'flexblog');
    if ( $value === true ) {
        $placeholder = esc_html__('Type and hit Enter...', 'flexblog');
    }

    $form  = '<form method="get" action="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'" class="infinity-search" >';
    $form .= '<input id="s" class="search_input" type="text" name="s" placeholder="'. $placeholder .'">';
    $form .= '<button type="submit" class="submit button" name="submit" ><i class="fa fa-search" ></i></button>';
    $form .= '</form>';

    return $form;
}
add_action( 'init', 'infinity_search_form', *A NUMBER LARGER THAN THE PARENT DECLARATION*);
```

Here's the section of the WordPress codex that may be helpful:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php

and here's a tutorial guide that may explain it all in greater detail:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623

**--- UPDATED 2018-12-17 ---**
In the event that re-declaring the method is not supported by the parent theme, then you would probably have to try one of the 2 following solutions:

1) Try removing the parent function and re-declaring it in your child theme functions.php file: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273941/how-to-override-parent-theme-function-through-the-child-theme#answer-273955

2) Follow the note from ArtisticPhoenix, and create your own function, which you call on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the information, unfortunately I still wasn't able to make it work. The function I mentioned in my question seems to not be pluggable, so I tried the whole priority thing, adding a number (11 first, then went all the way to 50) at the end of the "add_filter" part at the end of the function, but it didn't work.

`add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'infinity_search_form', 11 );`

Comment: This is the error I get when loading my website:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare infinity_search_form() (previously declared in /home/ovidiuav/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/flexblog-child/functions.php:147) in /home/ovidiuav/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/flexblog/functions.php on line 494

Comment: Thanks for all the information, also tried removing it and it still didn't work. I guess I'm just doing something wrong. At this point I feel like I'm in over my head so I think I'll just give up for now. Thanks for everything!